# Selenium C# CssSelector using

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get element inside other element, but this element is not child.

Example code:

```
<form action="/Contact/SendContactForm" id="TopContactForm" method="post">
    <div id="contactform" name="contactform">
        <div id="contactformcontainter" class="clearfix">
            <input id="SenderName" name="SenderName" type="text" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

How can i simply get SenderName inside TopContactForm? I'm asking because there is two contact forms with same input id's and name's.

Comment: Does `div#contactformcontainter > input` do the trick? Or there are also few `div` elements with same `id` values? P.S. tell your developers that it's not a good idea to set same `id` to different elements :)

Comment: I forget about one thing. #TopContactForm id is only way to identify this form, second form have same structure.

Comment: I guess `form#TopContactForm > div > div > input` should work

Comment: Mmm, there is a way to get this input inside #TopContactForm aside from these two divs?

Comment: `form#TopContactForm input` should also works

Comment: did u try XPath ?

Comment: @Andersson That is exactly what i needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: Footnote: duplicate ids are a bug. Let your developers know so they can fix it.